# Chunked memory stream is empty

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a file in chunks using a file stream and write the buffered parts into a memory stream.

```
private Stream GetStream(string path)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];

            int iByteSize = 0;

            while ((iByteSize = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                //fs.Flush();

                if (iByteSize <= 0)
                {
                    memoryStream.Close();
                    break;
                }

                //fs.Position = 0;

                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, iByteSize);
            }

            return memoryStream;
}
```

The memory stream returned is empty. Could anyone tell me what is missing from the provided implementation?

Comment: Did you check if the _path_ variable passed refers to an actual _non empty_ file?

Comment: Yes, the path is pointing to non empty files.

Comment: Aside: You can remove the `if (iByteSize <= 0)` part, because that condition will never be true.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: If you're going to read the entire file into a memory stream, you might as well do `var memStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path));`. This will allocate only one buffer of the correct size, and the `MemoryStream` will use the same buffer - no redundant copies will be made at all. Code is simpler *and* more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably when you try to read the MemoryStream you have not set the initial position.
Indeed after the call to GetStream the [Position property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.position?view=netcore-3.1) points to the last byte loaded in the MemoryStream.

If you want to read starting from the init you need to reset the Position property like

```
string file = @"e:\temp\txt.dat";
var x = GetStream(file);
x.Position = 0;    
byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
x.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Or as a better alternative, you can reset that property in the GetStream method itself just before returning

```
private Stream GetStream(string path)
{
    .....
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return memoryStream;
}
```

Comment: resetting the memory stream position just before returning it solved the problem for files not bigger than 2GB..for bigger files now I am getting 'Stream too long'...

Comment: @tsiro MemoryStream can only hold up to 2Gb. You should rethink your code if you are using files so large.